# conversion of Unicode hexadecimal number in excel to decimal

Tags: python, string, excel, unicode

In Excel there is few number in hexadecimal format. I want to find its decimal equivalent in Python. Below is the code:

```
int(sheet.cell(2,2).value, 16)
```

as it is in Unicode it is not taking it as string and showing error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''

Comment: Please give some example data. Unicode strings work fine: ``int(u'0xAF', 16)``.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be the empty string. See your error message.

```
int("", 16)  # this will give ValueError
```

Comment: sheet.cell(2,2) is not an empty string... it does have a value

Comment: Well, your error message `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''` shows an empty string (Note **''** at the end of the message).